# How to initialize an std::array in the initializer list of a class without hardcoding the array's size

Tags: c++, arrays

I've got Foo.h:

```
#include <array>

class Bar {
public:
  Bar(std::string name) : name(name) {}

  std::string name;

};

class Foo {
public:
  enum {ARRAY_SIZE=10};

  Foo();

  void printElement(int idx);

  std::array<Bar,ARRAY_SIZE> myArray;

};
```

Foo.cc:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>

Foo::Foo(): myArray({Bar("9"),Bar("8"),Bar("7"),Bar("6"),Bar("5"),
                     Bar("4"),Bar("3"),Bar("2"),Bar("1"),Bar("0")}) {}


void Foo::printElement(int idx) {
  if (idx < ARRAY_SIZE) {
    std::cout << "Value is " << myArray[idx].name << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Index out of bounds" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.printElement(1);
}
```

The problem is that the
`{Bar("9"),Bar("8"),Bar("7"),Bar("6"),Bar("5"),Bar("4"),Bar("3"),Bar("2"),Bar("1"),Bar("0")}`
is too literal, I need to be able to use an expression which expands to the right size based on the value of ARRAY_SIZE (which could live in an external header file).

Note that in this example I must initialize `myArray` in the initializer list, otherwise I get this:

```
(...)/gcc/6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/array:90:12: error: no matching function for call to 'Bar::Bar()'
```

What's the best way to do it?

I'm using g++ 6.3.0 by the way.

Comment: myarray has the "right size" (i.e. ARRAY_SIZE) when you declare it. That is, you don't need to initialize a std::array to give it a size. The size is part of the array type.

Comment: Is the `ARRAY_SIZE` always fixed? Why not have it as a template parameter?

Comment: @Jasancos: This site has an edit history; when you update your question you don't need to keep old versions. That just confuses new readers.

Answer (score 4):

Use a helper function.  Add

```
template <std::size_t N>
auto make_array()
{
    std::array<Bar, N> arr;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        arr[i] = std::to_string(N - i - 1);
    return arr;
}
```

To your class and then you can use it in the member initializer list like

```
Foo::Foo(): myArray(make_array<10>()) {}
```

This only works through if `Bar` is default constructable.

For your code what you can do is add another helper that has a [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) of values to construct the `Bar`'s from and that would look like

```
// helpers for reversing an integer sequence
template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto indexSequenceReverse (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
   -> decltype( std::index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1U-Is...>{} );

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequenceReverse
   = decltype(indexSequenceReverse(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

class Bar {
public:
  Bar(std::string name) : name(name) {}

  std::string name;

};

class Foo {
public:
  enum {ARRAY_SIZE=10};

  Foo();

  void printElement(int idx);

  std::array<Bar,ARRAY_SIZE> myArray;

  // get sequence and expand out initializes 
  template <std::size_t ... Is>
  auto make_array_impl(std::integer_sequence<size_t, Is...>)
  {
      return std::array{ Bar{std::to_string(Is)}... };
  }

  // convenient forwarder to implementation
  template <std::size_t N>
  auto make_array()
  {
      return make_array_impl(makeIndexSequenceReverse<N>{});
  }

};

Foo::Foo(): myArray(make_array<10>()) {}

void Foo::printElement(int idx) {
  if (idx < ARRAY_SIZE) {
    std::cout << "Value is " << myArray[idx].name << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Index out of bounds" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.printElement(1);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the solution, but my original example didn't describe my problem. I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: @Jasancos No problem.  I've updated the answer to work for `Bar`'s

Comment: If you want `Bar("nine")`, `Bar("eight")`, etc you'll need a second helper function instead of `std::to_string` but this indeed is the right solution.

Comment: Isn't it a problem that `Bar` is not default-initialiuable?

Comment: @n314159 It is.  I'll update with a solution that works if it isn't, since the OP's new example isn't.

Comment: @nathanoliver This won't work anymore. ```std::array<Bar, N> arr;``` will cause a compilation error: ```error: no matching function for call to 'Bar::Bar()'```

Comment: @Jasancos Yeah.  It requires the `Bar` be default constructable.  I'm adding an update that will work when it isn't.  It'll just be a few minutes.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica many thanks for that. There's something I don't understand. Where's the definition of indexSequenceReverse ?

Comment: @Jasancos There isn't one.  That function works like `std::declval` works.  It exists solely to get a type that can be used.  It's a template meta programming technique.

Comment: If I try that I get ```Foo.h:36:24: error: missing template arguments before '{' token```. I think the body of ```make_array_impl()``` has to be ```return std::array<Bar, ARRAY_SIZE>{ Bar{std::to_string(Is)}... };```

Comment: @Jasancos If you can use C++17 the code will compile as is thanks to CTAD (Class Template Argument Decuction).  If you can't use C++17 then you need `return std::array<Bar, sizeof...(Is)>{ Bar{std::to_string(Is)}... };`